# Duality of the trace form

Tags: reference-request, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Can you suggest me references about the duality of the trace form of an extention of fields i.e. $K\subset L$ extention of field then $T: L \times L \rightarrow K$  where $T(x,y)=Tr_{L/K}(xy) $ is a duality.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest **Serge Lang - Algebra**. Edition of 2002. And in particular the chapter on Galois Theory, page. 284 and onward.

Comment: Really thank you!